# Efficiently unpack and reshuffle 8 shorts in arm neon

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

Imagine I have this input array:

```
uint16_t input[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 22, 33, 44 };
```

how can I get from this input four q-vectors with the following contents:

```
uint16x8_t q1 = { 11, 11, 1, 1, 11, 11, 1, 1 };
uint16x8_t q2 = { 22, 22, 2, 2, 22, 22, 2, 2 };
uint16x8_t q3 = { 33, 33, 3, 3, 33, 33, 3, 3 };
uint16x8_t q4 = { 44, 44, 4, 4, 44, 44, 4, 4 };
```

Preferably using neon intrinsics?

[Solution that I came up with](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoIL4WBAHQIN2DgAYAgnIVKVmdVqbEAtgH0WmVCyMnzVywD0AFR%2BqmGqIgoEtABsrgSqCgAOIgQcAKx86QAiDrkcAOw8qvSqXKSqshUALBW0pVzllVWq1dXqBdkafJbhqqIEKQQgoeGR%2BrEAHgAc8aoAjrR5HcX1daUb61sldR1dsj0WfePRMTNz81zLhcWNFXdl9/dNDy973aNhJ1OzCfOy1yKzQqshaYJBYPBlXeB0%2BESiPwu7Q0%2BSBbRqtVaNQxOKxrRhhyCAT8ADdUHh0KoCJgdBA0CwdPCJnECEFEiwhhVviy2egdABKPw3OH0xlkimqIJJZbJVIfSxwk6yLiTFVcOZMJjLEkMdDqkTKqCihJK9Ws/lJQWw3pjBFnX6qTValGqEnETBRTDEJLugjzVwiWIBmLVCAktDOABGCkwwdDmoMJKYDAyPDMGWyFQTSZTmVoGf5VsOxztk2qqo1k1oZm1IgAXkkA7Ew8BMARXAg8MAEK5BM2nfyKiTW%2B2GKgAO5NmIQAdFxWlh2RpfaiPRjxxmdVsyJ5Op9M5LNbne5nj5nJzm1fBdzZC37XuknK/2B6dLyMX/xHW3MssVhLoADtTrPBGxfFs21cMdJzA29kEHV0R0gicpzpW9C3lL8rx/cszVUTB8KAkCUOHCDO27FDYPgkj2zInsYLQj95x/B0AA0lhdN0PX0L0fTbZ8gxEEMw3QEQkn9Zh10E0NOM9b1fTjFCAPQY9UzPbJ4LMdDrUwplTnOBIWKuDj3Vk3i/SnDcSREsTINYWMpLDEzuLkiCpJQ/DMBUvMCwqTSPxLZi5hYgFjK46kXPMl9LOs8S7MspzwrMhSwKUry0x81Q/IwgK9NY5FZFyGTnLM/i4gcqzRNiyShKKxL5LcsCPLS/d1N8rTDjhEkdFoUqID5AgKjY/zwi66Jev6/hpkGrhhrCUaesUnR%2BFiQbZFm11uvGpbeC4TEWOqRjOj8KRBwYaR0ikUgWGkMxLtQaRNH4fhVGEMQJHULhZFoS7hikW7C1IABrEB0nSAxdumMxqloAoCnSap0hiABOLgYkYaRqku66/ru6RLsEEAzFIX7/tIOBYBgRAUFQZwkjwBgvXISgIzphniBQCTgHiYgRBYQHSAAM3p8KCYgSMbsutcnAAT2kb7SAjZxMH0AB5FgGFlnHSCwZxWGABmJe1vB3WQAg8BJGlDcwSZMGQVJJCkeXPTOrWCGIPBnAl069ZQJ7eEYPBIwJ2AWCYJWQEmQQPfQUgLfZt3ecBgHUCSM2vAJqQAFoVYBTOdHQFFOF4ZalkzggnBHR0XBDfHRHESRaFO86scN%2B6pBmGJM5DVQlD11QIATvn%2BX73BCBID6voqTQadZr0J8b1RHuL3gfq9wdgdkAoDHSdGpEx0hPfSInsdu0g2/xwnia9snKYgJAWfpxmKDpGfH/Z3u2G5xPBeFr1RfFrWUtiCa3lorZWBA1Ya0NjrPWBstb4BNmbC2GdT7W1tvbOWl1naGzdh7a%2BnNfbLwEAwQOwcICDhTmnBk0hs653zoXP2p5S7l2IJXJwzgSQFC1JnZwyAUiFxINSSYmcmC0HSKoHhAt%2BEFQ8F4CRzgBZjiYAQER0YUQICcOgWub0G5NykBdK6rdpAdy7u0D%2BwB%2B6DyTiPfARBiDzynq/NmE8ZqL0YavHGAMECYCYFgdm5Dd770PsfIxUgL5ExJiddeIA2gGDhrQJG6RpiNARtUWQZgCi1BdrIFuWtz5X08XorguTT75MiQDOOUcvAxKAA%3D) seems to produce optimal arm64, but armv7 seems not to be optimal. What can be improved or maybe entirely different approach is possible?

Note, that my sample code outputs q1, q2, q3 to some memory, in my actual code I need to calculate q1, q2, q3 before I can use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is way too complex.

- You should avoid `vcombine` since it mostly results in multiple
  unnecessary `vmov` equivalents.
- You should prefer `vtrn` over `vzip/vuzp` since `vtrn` is much faster.

---

```
void foo(uint16_t *input, uint16_t *output)
{
    uint16x8_t q0, q1, q2, q3;
    uint16x4x2_t data1, data2, result1, result2;

    data1 = vld2_u16(input);
    data1.val[0] = vrev64_u16(data1.val[0]);
    data1.val[1] = vrev64_u16(data1.val[1]);

    data2 = data1;

    result1 = vtrn_u16(data1.val[0],data2.val[0]);
    result2 = vtrn_u16(data1.val[1],data2.val[1]);

    vst1_u16(&output[0], result1.val[1]);
    vst1_u16(&output[4], result1.val[1]);
    vst1_u16(&output[8], result2.val[1]);
    vst1_u16(&output[12], result2.val[1]);
    vst1_u16(&output[16], result1.val[0]);
    vst1_u16(&output[20], result1.val[0]);
    vst1_u16(&output[24], result2.val[0]);
    vst1_u16(&output[28], result2.val[0]);
}
```

That above should run much faster than yours on both `aarch32` and `aarch64`

---

Hand written assemblies:

`aarch32`

```
vld2.16     {d4, d6}, [input]!

vrev64.16   d4, d4
vrev64.16   d6, d6
vmov        d5, d4
vmov        d7, d6
vmov        q0, q2
vmov        q1, q3

vtrn.16     q2, q0
vtrn.16     q3, q1

vst1.16     {q0, q1}, [output]!
vst1.16     {q2, q3}, [output]!
```

---

`aarch64`

```
ld2     {v2.4h, v3.4h}, [input], #16

rev64   v2.4h, v2.4h
rev64   v3.4h, v3.4h
trn2    v0.4h, v2.4h, v2.4h
trn2    v1.4h, v3.4h, v3.4h
trn1    v2.4h, v2.4h, v2.4h
trn1    v3.4h, v3.4h, v3.4h

mov     v0.d[1], v0.d[0]
mov     v1.d[1], v1.d[0]
mov     v2.d[1], v2.d[0]
mov     v3.d[1], v3.d[0]

st1     {v0.8h-v3.8h}, [output], #64
```

---

That `vrev` has to be performed changes quite a lot.

Below is a "cheap" suggestion utilizing `vtbl` which makes sense if the routine is to be executed within a loop.

```
void foo(uint16_t *input, uint16_t *output)
{
    uint8_t *pSrc = (uint8_t *) input;
    uint8_t *pDst = (uint8_t *) output;

    uint8x8x2_t data;
    uint8x8_t d0, d1, d2, d3;

    const uint8x8_t mask0 = {8, 9, 8, 9, 0, 1, 0, 1};
    const uint8x8_t mask1 = {10, 11, 10, 11, 2, 3, 2, 3};
    const uint8x8_t mask2 = {12, 13, 12, 13, 4, 5, 4, 5};
    const uint8x8_t mask3 = {14, 15, 14, 15, 6, 7, 6, 7};

    data.val[0] = vld1_u8(pSrc++);
    data.val[1] = vld1_u8(pSrc++);

    d0 = vtbl2_u8(data, mask0);
    d1 = vtbl2_u8(data, mask1);
    d2 = vtbl2_u8(data, mask2);
    d3 = vtbl2_u8(data, mask3);

    vst1_u8(pDst++, d0);
    vst1_u8(pDst++, d0);
    vst1_u8(pDst++, d1);
    vst1_u8(pDst++, d1);
    vst1_u8(pDst++, d2);
    vst1_u8(pDst++, d2);
    vst1_u8(pDst++, d3);
    vst1_u8(pDst++, d3);
}
```

---

Last but not least, probably the fastest routine for a single iteration which can be further boosted when written in assembly.

```
void foo(uint16_t *input, uint16_t *output)
{
    uint16x4x4_t data;

    data = vld4_lane_u16(input++, data, 2);
    data = vld4_lane_u16(input, data, 0);

    data.val[0] = vsli_n_u32(data.val[0], data.val[0], 16);
    data.val[1] = vsli_n_u32(data.val[1], data.val[1], 16);
    data.val[2] = vsli_n_u32(data.val[2], data.val[2], 16);
    data.val[3] = vsli_n_u32(data.val[3], data.val[3], 16);

    vst1_u16(output++, data.val[0]);
    vst1_u16(output++, data.val[0]);
    vst1_u16(output++, data.val[1]);
    vst1_u16(output++, data.val[1]);
    vst1_u16(output++, data.val[2]);
    vst1_u16(output++, data.val[2]);
    vst1_u16(output++, data.val[3]);
    vst1_u16(output, data.val[3]);
}
```

---

`aarch32`

```
vld4.16     {d2[2], d3[2], d4[2], d5[2]}, [input]!
vld4.16     {d2[0], d3[0], d4[0], d5[0]}, [input]

vsli.32     q1, q1, #16
vsli.32     q2, q2, #16

vmov        q0, q1
vmov        q3, q2

vswp        d1, d2
vswp        d6, d5

vst1.16     {q0, q1}, [output]!
vst1.16     {q2, q3}, [output]
```

---

`aarch64`

```
ld4     {v0.h, v1.h, v2.h, v3.h}[2], [input], #8
ld4     {v0.h, v1.h, v2.h, v3.h}[0], [input]

sli     v0.2s, v0.2s, #16
sli     v1.2s, v1.2s, #16
sli     v2.2s, v2.2s, #16
sli     v3.2s, v3.2s, #16

mov     v0.d[1], v0.d[0]
mov     v1.d[1], v1.d[0]
mov     v2.d[1], v2.d[0]
mov     v3.d[1], v3.d[0]

st1     {v0.8h-v3.8h}, [output]
```

Comment: vcombine actually results in no code (mostly), as compiler is smart enough to allocate registers in such way so that both parts of vcombine are already in subparts of a q-register.

Comment: oops, I forgot `rev`

Comment: output++ updates only by one short, you need to move by 4!

Comment: note, that all places where you use `++` (for inputs and outputs) are not correct. In my actual code I need to end up with 4 uint16x8_t registers that contain these lanes, and this is a one time thing, so, vtbl solution wouldn't be optimal for my case.

Comment: Check [this solution](https://godbolt.org/g/PHp7WT) based on your first suggestion. Even though it uses vcombine and others generated asm for arm64 is good, could be better for armv7 though. It allows rev64 and vtrn to be done in one operation operating on q-regs instead of doing that on d-halves. Note, as stated in my question I actually need to get q1, q2, q3 etc, I store them to output simply for correctness check and to ensure that compiler doesn't optimize them away on godbolt.

Comment: @Pavel You are right. `++` doesn't work which means one more reason NOT to use intrinsics since it means even more performance hit, especially on the weaker cores.

Comment: @Pavel And I was talking about `vmov` equivalents. I tried to talk the compiler into generating machine codes similar to my assembly ones: [here](https://godbolt.org/g/66r99N). As you can see, there are tons of instructions I never even dreamt of.

Comment: Yes, in this example compiler isn't smart enough to handle it. Seems that when x4 involved it cannot "combine" it properly. Or perhaps because these were loading with vld4_lane. Even if you remove it all and try to store qdata[0] and [1] you'll get these moves. Interesting that for second part of combine it generates vtbl :) I'm trying to test with armcc, this one I expect to be much better at figuring out neon. I'm trying to optimize a few simple functions to refresh my rusty neon knowledge and your tips were very helpful.